# GitLab/GitHub for issue Tracking?

Tags: tools, defect-tracking

Has anyone used these? I'm in the market for a simple issue tracking tool and all of our code bases are stored on GitLab (or they have been). We have a relatively small team and while I was looking for Issue tracking tools for our team I thought....well heck why not use GitLabs integrated Issue tracking tool?

(Since the users are there and it's "free" as in we've been using it so it wouldn't cost any additional money)...is there really any downside to this?

I mean for a Huge team it might not make sense, but our team is only like 4-5 devs and 1 qa (me)...it seems like a fine solution?

Anyone using it have any pro's/con's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any serious tool can be used effectively in a small team. 
However, learn and explore the tools are important; its secondary features can be crucial.

Regarding GitHub issue tracking, it's important to not only register bugs and issues, but also use it completely: Address the issue to milestones (end of sprint, e.g.), correctly label, etc, etc.

One team will probably have problems if the tool do not fit its process of development. The most important resource is the people, and tools must be used to improve the way people do their craft, not pivot it.